# How can I get my code to return the correct variable?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Menu extends AirPorts{
    
    public static String checkerUK() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid = false;
        String ukAP = "";
        while(valid == false) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the code of the UK AirPort ");
            ukAP = sc.next();
            if(ukAP.equalsIgnoreCase(ukOne)) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
            if(ukAP.equalsIgnoreCase(ukTwo)) {
                valid = true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Please try again");
            }
            sc.close();
        }
        return ukAP;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get checkerUK to return the ukAP within the while loop. The current error I have is,

```
ukAP cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

for line, `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`. It seems to be that `ukAP` is local to the while loop, and I have tried to put, "return ukAP" within the while loop but then I get an error saying that checkerUK needs to return a String, so it doesn't recognise it.

I have also tried to create a public/global ukAP for the whole class but that doesn't have any affect on the ukAP within the while loop.

I'm using Eclipse and Java 14.

Comment: Eclipse is not related to your question.

Comment: You are closing the `Scanner` object in the `while` loop.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. If I remove `extends AirPorts` (since lack code for that class makes it unusable) my IDE complains about lack of `ukOne` and `ukTwo`. BTW don't close Scanner which is handling `System.in` since it will also close `System.in` and prevent you from reading more data from user/console in current lifecycle of your application. Expecially don't do it in a loop because next iteration will be unable to use `System.in` and `sc.next();` will complain about it by throwing `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: This info cannot be correct. There is no way `ukAP` cannot be resolved in line `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`, when it is not used there.

Comment: Did you try ``return ukAP;``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
public static String checkerUK() {
    final String ukOne = "LTH";
    final String ukTwo = "LGW";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean valid = false;
    String ukAP = "";
    System.out.print("Please enter the code of the UK AirPort: ");
    while (valid == false) {
        ukAP = sc.nextLine();
        switch (ukAP) {
            case ukOne:
            case ukTwo:
                valid = true;
                break;
            default:
                valid = false;
                System.out.print("Please try again: ");
        }
    }
    return ukAP;
}
```

Java supports [string switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) since Java 7. The values must be constant, though. That's why I declared them as `final`.

Never close a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in`.